# How to search special characters(+ ! \ ? : ) and an text in lucene

Tags: lucene

searchQuery : "A/S stack"

i use :

```
`query = parser.Parse(searchQuery.Trim());
```

result : 0 record

//////

searchQuery : "A/S"

i use :

```
query = parser.Parse(searchQuery.Trim());
```

result : 0

//////

searchQuery : "A/S"

i use :

```
query = parser.Parse(QueryParser.Escape(searchQuery.Trim()));
```

result : 56

///////

searchQuery : "stack"

i use :

```
query = parser.Parse(QueryParser.Escape(searchQuery.Trim()));
```

result : 0 record

///////

searchQuery : "stack"

i use :

```
 `query = parser.Parse(searchQuery.Trim());`
```

result : 25 record

how to search Escaping Special Characters and one text with lucene ?

Comment: Which `Analyzer` are you using?

Comment: i use :   var analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer(Version.LUCENE_30);

Comment: no answer ?......................

Comment: StandardAnalyzer will tokenize those input strings as separate words. Use a custom one.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Keyword Analyzer](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_6_0/analyzers-common/org/apache/lucene/analysis/core/KeywordAnalyzer.html) to tokenize the entire stream while indexing.

Have a look at [this](http://lucene.apache.org/core/2_9_4/queryparsersyntax.html#Escaping%20Special%20Characters) to escape special characters in query parser.